# Big O time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, landau-notation

I have a question if I have my $k=300$
and my loop is like this :

```
for( int x = 0 ; x<n ; x--){
    for(int y=0 ; y<k; y++){
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this still $O(n^2)$? If no, why?
Thank you :)

Comment: something is wrong there. Is $k=x$? if so then indeed it is $O(n^2)$, and exactly $n\frac{n+1}2$  (up to $\pm1$ in each term, due to less-than vs less-than-equal, etc.). If $k=300$, then this is exactly $300\cdot n=O(n) = O(n^2)$.

Comment: @RanG. Thank you, but I'm not following when you say O(n) = o(n^2) because O(n) is the best case scenario for my loop and  o(n^2) is the worse... So, which one is then?

Comment: Check [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/57/157) to understand why $n=O(n)=O(n^2)=(O(f(n))$ for any $f$ that grows at least as fast as $n$ (i.e., it's an upper bound. Maybe not a tight bound, but still an upper bound)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you meant `x++` rather than `x--`, the complexity is $\Theta(nk)$. Since $k = 300$, you can simplify that to $\Theta(n)$. As Ran G. mentions, since $n = O(n^2)$, then your loop is also $O(n^2)$. It's also $O(2^n)$. But the tight analysis is $\Theta(n)$.

Comment: x++, x--, what does it matter.. anyways on any given computer it is $O(1)$  (-;

Comment: @RanG. if there will be `x--` then `x` will be smaller then $n$ for a long time, until reach `INT_MIN` and turn to `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @Bartek Indeed, however I meant that `INT_MAX`,`INT_MIN` are both O(1) (say, $2^{64}$ ?), so the loop anyhow runs less than, say $O(($`INT_MAX`$-$`INT_MIN`$)^2)=O(1)$..